# superset error "Your dashboard is too large. Please reduce the size before save it"

Tags: apache-superset

I have this dashboard with many charts. Whenever I try to save any change I make I get this error saying

> Your dashboard is too large. Please reduce the size before save it

I tried the following, but these didn't work:

- Tried to modify the parameter `SUPERSET_DASHBOARD_POSITION_DATA_LIMIT` in `superset/superset/config.py`
- Tried modifying the type data of the column `json_position` in the DB

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Setting `SUPERSET_DASHBOARD_POSITION_DATA_LIMIT` should fix this issue for you. Eventually you will hit the limit of TEXT columns in your db, so make sure the value you set is <= the limit on the db you're using. For postgres the max value is 1GB